# Best way to delete among Parent and child relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to optimize code using the Hibernate relations + cascades.  I might know the solution, but need your expert opinion on it.

I have a table A, This table has two onetomany relations with table AA(owner ie,. FK of A) and AB(owner ie,. FK of A). Bi directional relation.

Now I want to delete A and all the related data in AA and AB.

Will session.delete(A,id) be enough? if so, what should the cascading type be on these tables?

If possible could you mention the JPA secific cascade. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqm it has descriptions on each Cascade type

session.delete is sufficient once you define correct Cascade types